# Unit Testing with Jest and React - Axios Get Inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, use-effect

How do I write a unit test in Jest for the initializePlayers function inside the useEffect?
Test if the call is working?

```
export default function App() {

...

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializePlayers = async () => {
      await axios.get(url)
      .then(async res=> {
        const activePlayers = res.data.filter(p => p.active === true);
        setPlayers(activePlayers);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }

    initializePlayerPool();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this example.

```
import React from "react";
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
import axios from "axios";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import App from "./App";
jest.mock("axios");

// mock data
const url= "YOUR_URL",
   
describe("App test", () => {
  let wrapper;

  // clear all mocks
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test("load app", async () => {
    // mock axios promise
    await act(async () => {
      await axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(url));
      wrapper = mount(<App />);
    });

    wrapper.update();
    await expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mr.Gandhi! I downgraded my React version and I also had to install enzyme-adapter-react.